# How can my client perform diego-ssh proxy authentication against an IBM Bluemix CloudFoundry App

Tags: ssh, ibm-cloud, sftp, scp, diego

I am interested in using client tools such as **ssh**, **scp** and **sftp** to interact with my IBM Bluemix CloudFoundry App.

> Specifically, there is a dynamically generated file/folder that is created by my app web installer that I would like to download locally to my laptop.

I've read about the recent Diego enablement and I'm interested in leveraging the diego-ssh proxy-authentication capabilities discussed [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/diego-ssh#cloud-foundry-via-cloud-controller-and-uaa).

Answer (score 0):

Using the Cloud Foundry cf [command line interface](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases) and following the diego-ssh guidance found [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/diego-ssh#cloud-foundry-via-cloud-controller-and-uaa), you can complete a client proxy authentication as follows:

```
    $ cf ssh-code | pbcopy # paste authorization code when prompted for password
```

This authorization code can then be used as a password to invoke commands such as:

```
    # Direct SSH Client Interaction
    $ ssh -p 2222 cf:$(cf app your_bluemix_app_name --guid)/0@api.ng.bluemix.net

    # Secure Copy
    $ scp -P 2222 -oUser=cf:$(cf app your_bluemix_app_name --guid)/0 my-local-file.json api.ng.bluemix.net:my-remote-file.json

    # Secure FTP Transfer (GET, PUT, ...)
    $ sftp -P 2222 cf:$(cf app your_bluemix_app_name --guid)/0@api.ng.bluemix.net
```

The key detail for Bluemix is knowing its CF API endpoint:

<kbd>**Region Name**</kbd>             <kbd>**CF API Endpoint**</kbd>     
     <kbd>US South Region</kbd>          <kbd>api.ng.bluemix.net</kbd>    
<kbd>United Kingdom Region</kbd>  <kbd>api.eu-gb.bluemix.net</kbd>  
       <kbd>Sydney region</kbd>         <kbd>api.au-syd.bluemix.net</kbd>

With some combination of these clients, you can seamlessly move files between local and Bluemix CF App environments to fulfill a variety of end-user dev needs.

Here is a sample interaction:

```
    $ sftp -P 2222 cf:$(cf app goldi --guid)/0@api.ng.bluemix.net
    The authenticity of host '[api.ng.bluemix.net]:2222 ([158.85.156.18]:2222)' can't be established.
    RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8.
    Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
    Warning: Permanently added '[api.ng.bluemix.net]:2222,[158.85.156.18]:2222' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
    cf:59xxxxx3-4xxa-4xxx-xxxe-x0x@api.ng.bluemix.net's password:
    Connected to api.ng.bluemix.net.
    sftp>
```